# Embed a TradingView widget into google app maker

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I am not sure how to embed this code within Google App Maker. 
I need help creating a "client script" that I can call using an HTML block to display the widget.

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
<div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
<div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a 
href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/technicals/" 
rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Technical Analysis 
for AAPL</span></a> by TradingView</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external- 
embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
{
"width": 425,
"height": 410,
"symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
"locale": "en",
"interval": "1D"
}
</script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Comment: I would start looking at putting your code inside an HTML widget. You will likely need to set the widget to allow unsafe HTML. Not sure that this will do what you are looking for since your question is not very detailed.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I realised that the Html blocks don't run Javascript. I think i have to create a client side script and then bind the Html block to the script somehow?